# Как установить переменную окружения в windows?

Tags: windows

Как установить переменную окружения в windows?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Для единовременного действия переменной, надо открыть консоль и выполнить команду

```
set VAR_NAME=VAR_VALUE
```

Для постоянного действия переменной, надо перейти в "Мой компьютер" нажать правую клавишу мыши, выбрать свойства, вкладку "Расширенные". Далее выбрать "Переменные окружения". В появившийся форме создать новую переменную.